# Keywords heading and text centered

Tags: keywords

I would like to have a keyword paragraph with "Keyword" and text centered just as "Abstract" and its text is centered under `\begin{abstract} ... \end{abstract}`. How may I do this?

Comment: the setting of abstract (if it is defined at all) greatly varies between different document classes, so you would need to say which class you are using. the answer is simply to copy the definition and change abstract to keywords, in any case

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the suggestion. Under the ams package I don't seem to have access to a definition of abstract.

Comment: if your class allows you to have `\begin{abstract}` then the definition will be in that class, If you are using `amsart` then look at line 837 of `texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsart.cls`  which is: `\newenvironment{abstract}{%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\newenvironment{keyword}{%
  \centering Keyword \par}{}
% ...
\begin{keyword} Your text \end{keyword}
```

Change to suit your taste.